# Best way to create table in Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I'm trying to create a table like [this](http://images.monstermarketplace.com/casino-supplies-and-poker-chips/96-x-42-texas-holdem-poker-table-blue-changeable-felt-800x600.jpg)

On blender I create shape with a bezier circle to get a shape rounded on left and right, and straight on top and bottom. Then, I create cylinder and apply a curve modifier to my shape. I make [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3638H.png). But as you can see the cylinder isn't smooth at all and textures works hardly.

So, what is the best way, for you, to achieve this table (without the stuff on it and the legs) ?

For information I need to export it on theejs after.

Comment: Hi Rotan, that's a blender software question and not a programming question, and thus is completely off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.For the table top add a circle:

[image]

2.then modify this circle to this shape:

[image]

convert the above object to curve by pressing alt-c and choose "Curve from mesh/text"

3. then add in another curve->bezier circle and then scale it to 1/4th its size
4. select the previous curve and in its curve properties tab under the geometry tab in Bevel object option select the newly added bezier circle[image]

this should give you a general idea to make the rounded corner edge for your table, you can then modify this technique to complete your task